# I get errors when i load database data into Checkedlistbox in C# winform

Tags: c#, windows

I am working with the checkedboxlist where i add the function of drag and drop from one checkedboxlist1 to another checkedboxlist2

1:   this is first error
when i bind checkedboxlist with the database it show me the database data in to checkedboxlist1 but when i drag to second checkedboxlist then it give me System.Data.Datarow . i shown in image .
[image]

The second error image
[image]

the second error occure when i do not comment this line

checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);

the second error image is this

2 :   this is second error
System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

my code for fetching data into checkedboxlist is below.

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conec"].ConnectionString);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Mytodo_Task  ", connection);
da.Fill(dt);
//  checkedListBox1.DataSource = null;
checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Task";

anyone help me...to solve my problem

Comment: You need to update the data source, do not manipulate the UI controls directly.

Comment: i try different things but not get result which i want!!!!